# PHP PDO SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'events'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I connect to the database using MySQLi, everything works as it should, but with PDO or with CI database methods, I get this error : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'events'.

```
try {
            $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=events;");
            $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_MODE, PDO::ERR_MODE_EXCEPTION);

            //create statement;
            $statement = $link->prepare($sql);
            $statement->bindParam(":username", $login_request["username"]);
            $statement->bindParam(":password", $login_request["password"]);
            $statement->execute();

            $rows = $statement->fetchColumn();

            return ($rows == 1) ? true : false;
        }
        catch(PDOEXCEPTION $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Comment: events is a keyword so you may have to enclose the name in back-ticks i.e. `events`

Comment: Do you not need a database username and password in your PDO constructor?

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: ^ what do you mean by that? had you posted full code, this would have been solved within mere seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to connect like this.
Put it in a separate file connection.php and include it in every page you run queries

```
try{
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=YOUR_DB_NAME;charset=utf8', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD',
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    die('Error connecting to database');
}
```

then you can run queries in every page like this

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=:id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfect.

Comment: select it as best answer please if it worked for you